# R: to plot several ts on the same graph

Tags: r, plot, time-series

In R program I have made a list of ts (or I can use data frames, I don't know, what is better). Each of them looks like:

```
01-02-2013  02-04-2014    05-06-2014....
3.454        2.000        1.77....
```

Each date corresponds to a value. The periods between the dates are different.

1. I want to play with a time unit. For example I want to gather all the dates for three month and calculate mean value and then plot. Is it somehow simply possible in R to group data for a period? (I don't know the start date and don't know the final date)
2. So I have a list of such ts-s. I want to plot them to the same graph with different colors. Is it possible?

P.S. If 1. in this variation is too complicated, may be you can help me with the same question applying to data frame which looks like:

```
date       value  
20-01-2013 3.555
28-02-2013 1.333
01-10-2013 0.44
02-07-2014 0.56 
...
```

Comment: It is possible in R to group data for a period, it is also possible to plot several lines in one graph with different colors, but apart from that, your question is not clear enough to give a good answer.

Comment: A clear explanation of "I want to play with a time unit. For example I want to gather all the dates for three month and calculate mean value and then plot." and "So I have a list of such plots"

Comment: I explained: I have values a list of ts/data frames. Each ts/data.frame contains values for dates. Dates are not periodic, they are random. For each ts/data.frame I want to gather values within time periods and calculate mean value. Time period should be several months, for example, 3 months. Then I want to plot all the gathered-by-time-period values on the same graph. "Play" means that I want to try different time units: 3 months, 4 months.... and compare result plots. When I have them

Answer (score 0):

1. `aggregate(meandate$value ,list(date = cut(meandate$date, breaks="3 month")), FUN=mean)`, where meandate is the source data.frame and "3 month" is a desirable time unit